# Should answers that reference a user link to that user's profile?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, users

I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318277/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-custom-dynamic-class-with-dynamic-linq-using-xelement). The user answered it himself and referenced another answer and user "Paolo Tedesco".

I was thinking to link "Paolo Tedesco" to his profile.

Is that a good idea?

How do you link to profiles? I thought I could use @ to start a link to a user, but that doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: No, not really. Link to *relevant things* in the answer. Someone looking at that user's profile is not, at all, helpul. Like Bill says, link to the answer. *That's* relevant, and already has a link to their profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case I think it's more relevant to link to the answer itself (so I went ahead and added the link).

To answer your question, just adding '@' to a user name doesn't automatically link it to the user's profile like it does on some social media sites.  On Stack Exchange sites you just have to manually edit the link into the post.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the @ aspect.